# Why are the nexus devices needing surfaceview to work with the torch mode?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I know that the Google Nexus devices are needing a surfaceview to work with the torch mode for opening the flashlight. And I did update my flashlight app, so it's working now with nexus devices AND "normal" devices. But I don't understand why the Google Nexus devices are needing that surfaceview...

Could someone explain it to me?